# error while using react native firebase messaging with react native firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

Hi I am not able to build my project with when i install
[React Native Firebase - Messaging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/messaging)

My package json is like this

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.2",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.0.2",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.0.2",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.0.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
"react-moment": "^0.9.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-calendar": "^0.13.1",
"react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-gridview": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-label-select-v2": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.0.5",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.5",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.3",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.2"
  },
```

Error :

[image: Build error]

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` folder and the re-installing all of the depencies

Comment: @VilleKoo already tried but not working

Comment: hey its working fine after uninstall node_modules and pod file